# Hyperlink doesn't work in IE10 and Chrome 28(Load Main.aspx.cs everytime a link is clicked in Main.aspx)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

In Main.aspx i have:

```
  <div data-role="collapsible" data-content-theme="c">
    <h3>Sort</h3>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" >
        <li><a href="Main.aspx?OrderTime">OrderTime</a></li>
                <li><a href="Main.aspx?Person">Person</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

     <div data-role="collapsible" data-content-theme="c">
            <h3>Filter</h3>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d">
                <li><a href="Main.aspx?1">1 Day</a></li>
                <li><a href="Main.aspx?2">2 Days</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

If i click a link for the first time the method `Page_Load` in Main.aspx.cs is called. If i click the same link for the second time i am not getting inside Main.aspx.cs(Page_Load is called only if i click a link for the first time).

**EDIT** Now i tested with FireFox 22.0 and everything works fine. The problem occurs only with IE10.Page doesn't load after i click a link for the second time. It remembers the last click.

**Same problem with Chrome v28.**

**I tested with Safariv5.1.7 and everything works fine**

**If i right-click and open the link in a new tab than it works with IE10 too. Why right-click works and only left-click doesn't?**

Comment: I have experienced similar problems with ASP.NET and IE 10. I expect Microsoft to send some patches.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `IsPostBack` to your Page_load method, like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            yourinitcodegoeshere; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: the problem is that Page_Load is never called anymore with the same link

Answer (score 0):

First Change Your html code with this  `<a href="Main.aspx?OrderTime="/>` if not work use below

one day i have this problem with ie  i was fixed that with  [HTML5 Shiv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_Shiv) you can read more on [HERE](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) . thats nternet Explorer compatibility and version usage.

Comment: are u added html5hive.js ?

Comment: Yes i did. But no effect. I dont know why it doesn't work with IE